# Prevent jquery submit on enter press on specific field

Tags: jquery

How can I cancel the jquery submit from running when I press the enter key on a specific input field?

Something like this:

```
var $canSubmit = true;
$('#profile_form')
    .keyup(function(e){         
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.srcElement.name == 'countrySearch') {
            $canSubmit = false;
        } else
            $canSubmit = true;
    })
    .on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);

        if (!$canSubmit) return false;

        // first time enter is clicked when on countrySearch this is run as submit runs before keyup
        // i want all code here not to run when enter is clicked on input[name="countrySearch"]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use keypress insted of keyup and `e.target.name`

```
var $canSubmit = true;
$('#profile_form').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.target.name == 'countrySearch') {
        $canSubmit = false;
    } else {
        $canSubmit = true;
    }
}).on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!$canSubmit) {
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('this would submit');
    }

});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tazcu/1/

Comment: It is better to use e.preventDefault(); instead of return false; in this case. ref: http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, I think you should be using `e.which` to get the key code. I might be wrong, but I think that provides a more cross-browser solution than `e.keyCode`.

Anyway, here's what you asked for:

```
$('[name=countrySearch]')
    .keydown(function(e){         
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

I think you actually want to bind to the `keydown` or `keypress` event here rather than `keyup`, but I might be wrong about that as well :) Regardless, rather than doing your `e.srcElement.name` check, you can simply bind the event to the `countrySearch` element itself. Then, if the key code ends up being 13, you just prevent the default action (which, in this case, would be submitting the form). No need to set a messy global variable that will get checked when the `submit` event gets fired, because the `submit` event simply won't get fired!